# Как в пайтоне сделать из строки массив, только со словами состоящих из одинаковых символов

Tags: python, массивы, строки

Например из `'1176   GFSSS'` это `['11', '7', '6', '   ', 'G', 'F', 'SSS']`

Comment: приведите пожалуйста минимально воспроизводимый пример, в вашем вопросе нет вопроса, это задача, аля: я ничего не пробовал и сделайте все за меня пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой алгоритм:

```
def split(str):
    result = []
    for symbol in str:
        if (len(result) and
            symbol == result[-1][0]):
            result[-1] += symbol
        else:
            result.append(symbol)
    return result
```